# How to insert concatenated values from a data-frame into another data-frame in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating a **time_interval** column and adding it to an existing **Data-frame in Pyspark**. Ideally the time_interval will be in the "**HHmm**" format with the minutes being rounded down to the nearest 15 minute mark (815, 830, 845, 900, etc).

I have the spark sql code that does the logic for me but how do I take that value that's concatenated as string column and insert that into an existing Data-frame?

```
time_interval = sqlContext.sql("select extract(hour from current_timestamp())||floor(extract(minute from current_timestamp())/15)*15")

time_interval.show()

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|concat(CAST(hour(current_timestamp()) AS STRING), CAST((FLOOR((CAST(minute(current_timestamp()) AS DOUBLE) / CAST(15 AS DOUBLE))) * CAST(15 AS BIGINT)) AS STRING))|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                               1045|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

baseDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from test_table")
newBase = baseDF.withColumn("time_interval", lit(str(time_interval)))

newBase.select("time_interval").show()

+--------------------+
|       time_interval|
+--------------------+
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
|DataFrame[concat(...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

So the actual expected results should be just showing the actual string value in the new column i'm creating rather than this concatenated value from a data-frame. Something like below:

```
newBase.select("time_interval").show(1)
+-------------+
|time_interval|
+-------------+
|    1045     |                                                                                                                                           
+-------------+
```

Comment: try this: `newBase = baseDF.selectExpr("*, extract(hour from current_timestamp())||floor(extract(minute from current_timestamp())/15)*15 AS time_interval")`

Comment: thanks pault, "selectExpr" worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `time_interval` is a dataframe type, for this case need to **`collect`** and `extract the required value out from dataframe`.

***Try this way:***

```
newBase = baseDF.withColumn("time_interval", lit(str(time_interval.collect()[0][0])))
newBase.show()
```

**(or)**

By using **`select(expr())`** function:

```
newBase = baseDF.select("*",expr("string(extract(hour from current_timestamp())||floor(extract(minute from current_timestamp())/15)*15) AS time_interval"))
```

As [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault) mentioned in comments, using **`selectExpr()`** function:

```
newBase = baseDF.selectExpr("*","string(extract(hour from current_timestamp())||floor(extract(minute from current_timestamp())/15)*15) AS time_interval")
```

**Example:**

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> time_interval = spark.sql("select extract(hour from current_timestamp())||floor(extract(minute from current_timestamp())/15)*15")
>>> baseDF=spark.createDataFrame([1,2,3,4],IntegerType())
>>> newBase = baseDF.withColumn("time_interval", lit(str(time_interval.collect()[0][0])))
>>> newBase.show()
+-----+-------------+
|value|time_interval|
+-----+-------------+
|    1|         1245|
|    2|         1245|
|    3|         1245|
|    4|         1245|
+-----+-------------+
```